# How to specify two concrete type arguments for generic type with a single type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

community. I have the following situation. I am using java collections, lets say the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface for example. It is a generic interface with a type parameter E for its elements. In my case I know the type of the elements that are going to be inserted, but the problem is that two types of elements are going to be inserted. Lets say I have the class A and class B and they have nothing in common. The nearest common ancestor of A and B is the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class. The types A and B are not defined by me, so I can not change the type hierarchies. If I define my list like this:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

then only elements of type A will be allowed, and if I define it like this:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

then only elements of type B will be allowed. Is there any way to do a logical OR ? How to specify that I want elements of type A or type B and nothing else ? Or the java way is to make:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and to check the type on my own when I perform any list operations ?

Comment: Well, you answered the question yourself, unless A and B both have a common superclass before Object.. In which case <? extends S>

Comment: Can you explain the actual use of this?  What will you do with these objects when you take them out of the collection?  Cast them to A or B?

Comment: Well, you could indeed implement your own List interface. I don't think you'll be able to get much value with generics, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: You could wrap the elements in a custom type, but this solution is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, actually when taken out the elements are passed to an utility method which makes use of their toString,equals and hashCode methods. So far I can use the List<Object>. The problem is these 3 methods are overridden in class A and class B and I must ensure that only objects of these two types are allowed in the list. And class A and Class B share behaviour but not an interface.

Comment: @egelev: I think the inevitable conclusion is that class A and class B _should_ share an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, you'd need something like a union type, which Java doesn't provide. You gave the answer yourself: If you cannot modify the hierarchy, not even let A and B implement the same interface, then you'll have to use a `List<Object>` and do additional typechecks yourself.